# mongoose cannot push to deeply nested document multiple positional operator

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to push element to subfeatures nested document by using $push. but when i use like this ''modules.$.features.$.subFeatures'' 
    it gives me the multiple positional operator error. so I get the features document index as x but i cannot figure out which way I can append that value to the query. 'modules.$.features.x.subFeatures' doesn't working.

```
var x =2;

RolePermission.update({
    'role': roleID,
     'modules.name' : data.module,
     'modules.features.name': data.feature

}, {

    $push:{
             'modules.$.features.x.subFeatures': {
                name: data.name,
                value: false,
                icon: data.icon
             }
          }

    }
}, {
    upsert: true
}, function (err, event) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways:

1. use es6:

```js
$push:{
             [`modules.$.features.${x}.subFeatures`]: {
                name: data.name,
                value: false,
                icon: data.icon
             }
          }
```

2. without es6:

```js
var push = {$push: {}};
push.$push['modules.$.features.' + x + '.subFeatures'] = {
                name: data.name,
                value: false,
                icon: data.icon
             };
RolePermission.update({
    'role': roleID,
     'modules.name' : data.module,
     'modules.features.name': data.feature

},
push, 
{
    upsert: true
}, function (err, event) {

});
```

3. find the document, update it in code and save. It maybe a little slower but you won't have such problems.

Comment: that works like a charm, you saved my hours of time. thanks.